Problems with Python script and networks on Raspberry Pi
I have a Raspberry Pi 4 with PiSound attached.
I'm trying to receive data from a Pioneer CDJ via the ethernet port.
If I run sudo tcpdump -i eth0 udp port 50001 I get this:

pi@raspberrypi:~/udp_test $ sudo tcpdump -i eth0 udp port 50001
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v[v]... for full protocol decode
listening on eth0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), snapshot length 262144 bytes
11:47:48.060238 IP 169.254.252.162.7295 > 169.254.255.255.50001: UDP, length 96

confirming to me that I'm receiving the data and the hardware connection is correct. The data stream stops when I hit pause on the CDJ and picks back up when I hit play. This is exactly as expected.
However when I try to access this data with a python script, it receives nothing. This is the script I'm running:

import socket
UDP_IP = "0.0.0.0"
UDP_PORT = 50001


sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
sock.bind((UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))


print("Listening for data...")
while True:
    data, addr = sock.recvfrom(1024)
    print(f"Received data: {data}")

Does anyone have any idea what I am missing? I've spent too much time and money on this to let it go at this point
Any help would be greatly appreciated
I tried checking the hardware, the ip addresses, the firewall among other things.
I'm expecting to receive the data and then be able to process it.

Should you set up the socket for broadcasting? I.e. sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_BROADCAST, 1)? I can't really provide it as an answer, since I don't have a setup like yours to test it.
